# I can't get this Bootstrap thing working properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I'm trying to figure out how to make this website with Bootstrap(keep in mind I'm new to bootstrap) and the after figuring out how to put my nav bar on top of my carousel, everything worked out fine, but then when I tried to add content, it wouldn't pop up until I added a div tag, but once I did that it would go up to the top. I solved that by moving the nav code on top of the carousel. Now everything works the way I want it, but the carousel doesn't work. :/

Here's my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Kame Computers</title>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link href="C:\Users\Madcat3277\Desktop\Kame Computers\Css\bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="C:\Users\Madcat3277\Desktop\Kame Computers\Css\bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<header>
  <!-- Styles Declare the Carousel and font. -->
  <style>
    .navbar {
      position: absolute;
      top: 30px;
      z-index: 10;
      width: 100%;
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: 'swiss_721light_condensed';
      src: url('C:/Users/Madcat3277/Desktop/Kame Computers/Fonts/swiss721light-webfont.eot');
      src: url('C:/Users/Madcat3277/Desktop/Kame Computers/Fonts/swiss721light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('C:/Users/Madcat3277/Desktop/Kame Computers/Fonts/swiss721light-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('C:/Users/Madcat3277/Desktop/Kame Computers/Fonts/swiss721light-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('C:/Users/Madcat3277/Desktop/Kame Computers/Fonts/swiss721light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('C:/Users/Madcat3277/Desktop/Kame Computers/Fonts/swiss721light-webfont.svg#swiss_721light_condensed') format('svg');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }

  </style>
  <!-- End of Harry Styles. -->
  <font size="4" face="swiss_721light_condensed">
     </header>

      <!-- Anything goes. -->

     <body>
<!-- Start of the Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-clear">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
</nav>
    </div> <!--End Nav -->


<div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item ad1">
      <img src="https://bobingao.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/green_bird_sitting_on_tree_branch-wide.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item ad2">
      <img src="https://bobingao.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/green_bird_sitting_on_tree_branch-wide.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item ad3">
      <img src="https://bobingao.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/green_bird_sitting_on_tree_branch-wide.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
 <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    </div>

        <div class="container marketing">
      <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
          <img class="img-circle" data-src="http://placehold.it/140/">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details »</a></p>
        </div><!-- /.span4 -->
        <div class="span4">
          <img class="img-circle" data-src="http://placehold.it/140/">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details »</a></p>
        </div><!-- /.span4 -->
        <div class="span4">
          <img class="img-circle" data-src="http://placehold.it/140/">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details »</a></p>
        </div><!-- /.span4 -->
      </div><!-- /.row -->

      <hr class="featurette-divider">

      <div class="featurette">
        <img class="featurette-image pull-right" src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/img/examples/browser-icon-chrome.png">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">First featurette headling. <span class="muted">It'll blow your mind.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
      </div>



    </body>

       <script src="C:\Users\Madcat3277\Desktop\Kame Computers\JavaScript\jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
       <script src="C:\Users\Madcat3277\Desktop\Kame Computers\JavaScript\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     </body>
```

Comment: side note-- internal `stylesheets`are meant to go in the `head` tag,not a `header` tag

Answer (score 1):

You just have Carousel as the id of the carousel and in the carousel controls your href is linking to #myCarousel so just change the id of the carousel to myCarousel and it should work also you have two end body tags and the scripts should go above the end body tag and no you have no end html tag

Answer (score 1):

Your carousel is not working because the arrows are not linking to the correct slider ID in the `href` property. Change the property value from `#myCarousel` to the ID of your carousel, `#Carousel`:

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#Carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```